# Best Database for this, NOSQL vs MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, nosql

I have an App based around Events and Branches. I have two events ones with Branches and ones Without.

Both Events and Branches have a latitude and longitude.

An Event can have Multiple Branches. I want to sort these Events by Distance from another geo-coordinate.

For the Events with Branches it should use the location of its branches to work out how close it is and for the Events without it should use the location of the event itself.

Is this possible to do in MySQL without a performance hit ? Or am I using the wrong kind of Database ? Should I use another NOSQL database with a script to export the current MySQL and Pods data to it.

This is the basic query I'm using ATM with this Framework which adds a small bit of sugar (Obviously this wouldn't work in plain MySQL), Events without Branches don't seem to appear in the correct order.

```
SELECT 
  t.*, 
  DISTANCE(\"$latitude\", \"$longitude\", 
           IF(t.branches.latitude, t.branches.latitude, t.latitude),     
           IF(t.branches.longitude, t.branches.longitude, t.longitude)
  ) as distance 
FROM table as t 
ORDER BY distance.
```

Comment: How dynamic are your branches and events? How numerous are they? I suppose a spatial index should work in your case. See [this presentation](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL) regarding approaches and ballpark performance figures.

Comment: We update them via a CMS on the backend. The Location we want to see how far they are from, is got from the User's Location and may change.

Comment: I suppose you give spatial indexes a test. Fill a table with e.g. 10000 known points, try searching for N closes points to a random location. Look at `explain plan`, measure time, CPU load, memory load. Make sure you can hand-check the correctness of a result by hand. I suppose it would beat a hand-coded solution both by speed and resource consumption.

Comment: BTW what is incorrect in the order of events without branches? What are the events in your query — the contents of `t`?

Comment: The Events appear  than they should like it can't sort them correctly. T is the Table with the Events. I'll try that code out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if there is any sort of relationship between entities, you want SQL to reduce the overhead of managing these relationships. (businesss logic, select name where event = something)

if you want to use a database for plain storage, and do all the business logic and relationship management on your server side language(php, ruby, c# whatever it is), then NOSQL is better.

Comment: So I may not see a performance benefit manually processing these entries from NOSQL and sorting them myself. I would have to benchmark it.

Comment: yes, you most likely will not see a performance boost coding the logic yourself. i would use mysql personally.